# What does facebook OpenGraph API Upgrade v2.2 message "Set a maximum number of top level IDs that can be fetched in a single API call" means?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We run the facebook API Upgrade Tool from API version 2.1 to version 2.2.

We got the following message in the description.
"Set a maximum number of top level IDs that can be fetched in a single API call"
( [ref to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xke6t.png)
)

However, we are not quite sure what does that message means ??

Not sure whether it is "There's now a limit of 50 IDs which can specified in a single request using the syntax ?ids=ID1,ID2. This reduces the likelihood of timeouts when requesting data about a large number of IDs in a single request."
in the facebook changelog ( ref: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog ) ??

Answer (score 1):

It means that the syntax `?ids=id1,id2,id3,...` now has a limit of 50 ids that can be passed in one call.

If you are not using that syntax to fetch details for multiple objects in your app, then you can ignore this.